# Why is this limit not zero?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y) = \frac{y^3(x^2+2xy-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

I am to calculate the limit of this function as it approaches the origin along the path $y=x^{2/3}$. I keep getting $0$ for this but that is not supposed to be the answer. Why is 
this limit not equal to $0$?

Edit 1: I left out a few aspects of the problem which might be more important than I thought. The function I posted is actually the partial derivative with respect to x of another function. And I am to find the limit as those points are plugged into the partial and go to 0. Does that change anything in this question?

Edit 2: What happens if we approach the origin from the path y=0? 
This would mean it is (x,0) approaching (0,0). Is this limit 0 as well?

Comment: Perhaps the $2xy$ in the numerator should be just $2y$? Then you'll have nonzero limit.

Comment: Try $$y=x^{4/3}.$$

Comment: You're going to need to show what you did, because the limit at the origin _is_ zero (use of polar coordinates confirms this) and your choice of path should give that.

Comment: Regarding your edit:  It sounds like nothing changes.  If the limit is supposed to be of the partial, then the function whose partial it is will not enter in in a significant way.  Perhaps if you post the statement of the problem as a verbatim quote, we will see something else.

Comment: For edit 2:  yes, the limit is 0.  No matter the value of $x$ (excepting that it should be nonzero), the value $f(x,0)$ is 0 because of the $y^3$ in the numerator.

Comment: @BarrySmith Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Substituting in $y=x^{2/3}$, we get
$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2(x^2+2x^{5/3}-x^{4/3})}{(x^2+x^{4/3})^2}$$
Leading terms (those in which $x$ appears with the lowest exponent) are $x^{10/3}$ in the numerator and $x^{8/3}$ in the denominator, so it should go to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Put $y=x^{2/3}$ into your function:

$$f(x,x^{2/3}) = \frac{x^2(x^2+2x^{5/3}-x^{4/3})}{(x^2+x^{4/3})^2} = \frac{x^{10/3}(x^{2/3}+2x^{1/3}-1)}{x^{8/3}(x^{2/3}+1)^2}=x^{2/3}\frac{(x^{2/3}+2x^{1/3}-1)}{(x^{2/3}+1)^2}.$$

The latter expression clearly converges to $0$ as $x\to 0+$.

You might want to pass to polar coordinates and the show that this function is continuous at the point $(0,0)$ and hence the limit does not depend on the path $y=y(x)$ and is always zero.

Comment: I left out a few aspects of the problem which might be more important than I thought. The function I posted is actually the partial derivative with respect to x of another function. And I am to find the limit as those points are plugged into the partial and go to 0. Does that change anything in this question?